# HP Envy 4520 & Mac OS 11: will print but no longer scan after adding wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, hp-envy

The home setup is an iMac running Yosemite surrounded by an assortment of MacBooks, iPhones, and just for fun, an old Windows box and an Android. One member of the house just ran up a $250 bill using data because the wireless router was just too far away, so I finally bit the bullet and installed a Netgear wireless extender I bought early in January but avoided installing because Something Always Goes Wrong.

I couldn't get the mac and the extender to see each other, and even connected the mac to the extender's wireless network (usually the mac runs with WiFi off, as it's connected directly to the router).
This time I had to call technical support, who guided me to a nearby paper clip, and this time the thing actually worked.  But I noticed while registering my product that I could no longer scan the receipt.  The scanner worked fine a week ago -- I recently started a new job, and had to print, scan, and sign all kinds of docs, and did it at home, as the lowly HP was more reliable than the stuff at work.

Once the extender was working, I put the Mac back on wired mode, and pointed the printer at a different router (the better one).  I can print, but I can't scan. The HP Utility sort of knows about the printer, but says it can't provide any information.  `Open scanner` doesn't. I tried downloading a firmware update, but it spins forever, looking for the device. But when I try to print, it finds the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by reinstalling the printer.